# Can I play a follower of a deity similar to Xom?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, religions-and-deities

I have barely any experience in tabletop RPGs, but a friend of mine is planning to host something fantasy-esque (I suspect 3.5) in the near future, so I got the urge to try something similar to Xom's crazy/dynamic mechanics.

For those not familiar with roguelike computer games such as Dungeon Crawl Stone Soup and Powder, to put it briefly, in contrast to other deities who count your devotion in Piety, Xom is a deity whose actions are only influenced by how bored he is. If all is going too well for an adventurer, Xom might mutate the poor guy for the hell of it, suddenly cause him to sporadically teleport, or make an important inanimate object such as a flight of stairs to sprout legs and run away.

The question is, in D&D can I play a follower of a deity similar to Xom, and if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## You can follow a crazy god…

Rather than providing a big list of crazy gods, it's easier to find gods *of* madness and work from there. The domain Madness is both a [*D&D 3.5*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/clericDomains.html#madness) and [*Pathfinder*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/madness-domain) domain, and gods that grant their worshipers access to that domain are a good place to start when trying to locate a god crazy enough for your character in the setting you're using (e.g. [Eberron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religions_of_Eberron), the [Forgotten Realms](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Madness_domain_deities), [Golarion](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Madness_domain_deities), [Greyhawk](https://metzger.obsidianportal.com/wiki_pages/greyhawk-deities-master-list)).

### …But it's likely no god will be as crazy as [Xom](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Xom)…

When [Xom](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Xom) thinks you're boring, you're plagued with random badness, and, when Xom thinks you're interesting, you're granted random goodness. There are neither *Dungeons and Dragons 3.X* nor *Pathfinder* mechanics that reflect something like Xom's constant caprice because doing so is problematic on the tabletop.

Xom's interest in a particular character requires a degree of DM micromanagement of constant divine events both trivial and significant that is unsuitable to the tabletop. A [roguelike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) pulls this off because the random generation of effects happens in the background, but such elements are foregrounded—as they're managed by the DM not the processor—on the tabletop.

Also, while many players find randomness acceptable when the choice is theirs (such as when making skill checks or attack rolls), players are often less comfortable with random *events* seeming to just happen: for example, only a unique group of players is willing to get on board with the party being randomly affected by a [*symbol of pain*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsS.html#symbol-of-pain) (né [*symbol of torment*](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Symbol_of_Torment)) because *your* character's boring his god.

Finally, most settings find it difficult to manage casual, direct divine intervention based on character action. Again, a roguelike can monitor precisely a character's actions and place those action unerringly with regards to a particular deity's desires, but a tabletop roleplaying game's more expansive and free-ranging options make decisions about where, exactly, the DM should place a PC's actions with regard to his deity's desires much more difficult.

#### …Yet the variant faith feats might be an option

[*Complete Divine*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786932724)'s description of faith feats warns, "Faith feats impose significant constraints on character behavior, and they rely on DM judgment calls. Thus they may not be appropriate for every campaign" (86), but this DM has used them without getting socked by his players. The faith feats Pious Defense (86), Pious Soul (86), and Pious Spellsurge (87) allow the possessor to spend faith points to employ special abilities. Faith points are gained when the possessor performs special, DM-determined tasks for the possessor's picked deity. The DM could adjust Table 3–2: Faith Point Awards (86) to reflect a deity like Xom's interests.

Comment: This is definitely good. So, a closer look at the Madness domain deities is the first thing I'll look into,  and if appropriate for the campaign, faith feats.

Comment: @user1337 Sometimes quickly accepting an answer alienates users who might've also answered (and they might've answered differently or even *better*). That makes it best to wait at least a day before accepting an answer. (Don't worry about me; my feelings are unhurt by being unaccepted.)

Comment: +1 but it could be improved by expanding an the difference between a follower of a deity vs a Cleric (etc) of a deity. Especially since u mentioned domains. Not all followers get access to the granted domains...